# Kiom ofta estas la uzo de "en" kun temposubstantivoj?

Tags: prepositions

Mi pli ofte vidis tempoesprimojn en adverba formo aŭ enhavantajn *dum* ol enhavantajn *en*. Ekzemple ĉirkaŭ la radikoj *tag, nokt, semajn, semajnfin, monat, jar.*

De lernu.net:

> **En la tago** ni vidas la helan sunon, kaj **en la nokto** ni vidas la palan
>   lunon kaj la belajn stelojn

Ĉi tie mi do dirus *dum la tago* kaj *dum la nokto* aŭ *tage* kaj *nokte*.

Ĉu ĉi tia uzo kun *en* estas ofta?

Paranteze mi rimarkis ĝin sufiĉe ofte kiam oni parolas pri specifaj jaroj, jarcentoj, la estonteco aŭ la pasinteco:

- Mi vojaĝis al Usono en 2009
- En la estonteco homoj ne rigardos televidon.
- Oni ne havis aŭtojn en la 18a jarcento.

Answer (score 3):

Ekzistas klara diferenco inter *dum* kaj *en. Dum* indikas la daŭron, *en* ne. Via ekzemplo *Mi vojaĝis al Usono en 2009* estas tute ĝusta, sed la uzo de *dum* estus erara tie. Vi ja povas diri *Mi loĝis en Usono dum 2009* (vi daŭre loĝis tie) kaj kontraste *Mi ekloĝis en Usono en 2009* (difinita momento).

La adverbaj tempindikoj ne esprimas tiun nuancon. *Aŭtune de 2015 mi logis en Usono* kaj *Aŭtune de 2015 mi eklogis en Usono* ambaŭ estas ĝustaj laŭ mi.